# What do you call it when someone exposes themselves by speaking first out of tension when addressing a group of people about a culprit?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example: Someone in a group committed a crime or a wrong doing. No one saw them doing it it.

Upon discovery of the wrong doing, everyone is brought together to bring the matter to light.

The speaker addresses the group that this and that happened and so forth but doesn't say who did it.

During a pause, the culprit is the first to breaks the silence. Obviously due to unbearable tension. They don't confess, but rather just say anything to distract or lighten the mood.

What do you call this phenomenon?

Comment: Related? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533585/looking-for-a-phrase-or-idiom-to-say-that-only-guilty-people-act-guilty

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're looking for. Do you want the word for somebody who says something simply to break an uncomfortable silence (which might have nothing to do with guilt at all), do you want the word for somebody who breaks such a silence *because* they're guilty (but it doesn't lead to them giving themselves away), or do you want the word for somebody who accidentally "outs" themselves? What are the consequence of them saying in this situation, for instance, "I can't believe how hot it is!"

Comment: @Jason Bassford The 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word **blurt** is best suited for this, although whether a character blurts out a confession or not, is simply dependent on the context.
[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=blurt%20definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-in&client=safari) gives the following definition:

**blurt**

*/bləːt/*

*verb*

say (something) suddenly and without careful consideration.

*"she blurted out the truth"*

Answer (score -4):

This would be in specialist's terms a case of **seduction** ([psychological manipulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_manipulation#According_to_Simon))

> - Seduction: Manipulator uses charm, praise, flattery or overtly supporting others in order to get them to lower their defenses and give their trust and loyalty to the manipulator.

Comment: At a stretch, and figuratively, "seduction" *might* be the action of the person who addressed the group, but it is not the action of the confessor.

Comment: @Greybeard I don't believe at all that this type of behaviour is an exclusivity of group leaders or people in the public eye. I think the term is perfectly applicable to the culprit.